# Updating existing mongodb data MERN

Tags: express, crud, mern

So I'm creating a webpage with users, and when the user first signs up for the site they are prompted to input a first name, last name, email, etc. In the user's profile page, I added a form to change the users name. I'm able to get all the info I need into the back end, but I'm not sure of the syntax to actually update the database with it.

This is my router.put function. It accepts two parameters, with first being the first name that the user wants to change it to, and email to look up the user in the database.

```
router.put("/updateFirst/:first/:email", function(req, res) {
  console.log("------------update first hit------------");
  db.User.getUserByEmail(req.params.email)
    .then(res => {
      console.log("updateFirst res: " + res);
    })
})
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: This is my getUserByEmail function

```
module.exports.getUserByEmail = function (email, callback) {
  console.log("getUserByEmail", email)
  var query = { email: email };
  console.log(query);
  return User.findOne(query, callback);
};
```

Comment: Please give the content of the `getUserByEmail` method. Also, give us the `update` method if it available?

Comment: @dothuan I updated with the getUserByEmail method, I'm not sure about the update method, do you mean the front end function where the info is passed to the backend?

Comment: I mean in order to update the database, you need to have an update method in your backend.